Generating Functions Tiling Problem
I am asked to consider a  $1 × n$ rectangle $R_n$ whose vertices are
$(0, 0),(0, 1),(n, 0),(n, 1)$. First, I am asked to derive a closed form for the amount of ways $R_n$ can be covered with tiles of size $1 \times 1$ and $1 \times 2$. I did this by using the generating function $H(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}h_nx^n$, and I got the answer:
$$a_n= \frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\sqrt{5}} $$
where $\alpha= \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} , \beta = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$
I am getting stumped for the next question. It asks in how many ways can $R_n$ be covered by non-overlapping $\frac{1}{2} \times 1 \;\And\; 1\times\frac{1}{2}$
rectangular
tiles, if both kinds of tiles can be either blue or yellow. I suspect it may either be a composition of generating functions or a recursive relation that looks something like this:
$$b_n= 2b_{\frac{1}{2}, 1}+ 2b_{1,\frac{1}{2}} $$
but otherwise I am stumped. Any help would be appreciated

Note that in any such tiling (of the second kind you mentioned) any two tiles that overlap on the x-axis must be completely overlapping (ie, you can't lay them like bricks, because you'll be left with a 1/4 area 'hole' you can't get rid of.  So effectively we are dividing the horizontal space into blocks of horizontal length $1$ or $1/2$.

The first answer is just the Fibonacci sequence, isn't it?  If $F_n$ is the number of tilings of $R_n$, there are $F_{n-1}$ tilings that begin with a $1 \times 1$ tile and $F_{n-2}$ tilings that begin with a $1 \times 2$ tile.

Indeed, @RobertShore, the first answer is just the Fibonacci sequence, and the found expression is just Binet's Formula (https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Binet%27s_Formula)

Let $T_m$ denote the number of tilings of the second kind that can be done with $m$ regions of horizontal space of length $1/2$ and height $1$ (so you want $T_{2n}$).
Then each tiling either has a vertical tile all the way on the left or a pair of horizontal tiles for it's left two bits (by @Jair's comment). In the first case, there are $2T_{m-1}$ ways the tiling can proceed, since there are $T_{m-1}$ ways to tile the reminder, and that can happen for either a blue or a yellow tile on the left. Meanwhile, there are 4 ways a pair of horizontal tiles can be colored blue or yellow (two options for the top horizontal tile times two for the bottom), so that one has $4T_{m-2}$ tilings in total in that case. Thus we have the recurrence relation that $$ T_m = 2T_{m-1} + 4T_{m-2}$$.
For the base cases we note that there are 2 ways a $1 \times 1/2$ size region can be covered (with a blue or a yellow vertical tile), so $T_1 = 2$, and we also have that there's just the 1 empty covering when $m=0$, so $T_0 =1$.
Now presumably you could proceed like you did for the other part, but for completeness I'll point out it can be done with exponential generating functions. If we take the exponential generating function $$ \tau(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ then we have $$ \tau'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty T_{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n!} \hphantom{\sum\sum} \text{and} \hphantom{\sum\sum} \tau''(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty T_{n+2}\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
Hence $\tau$ satisfies the ODE that $$ \tau''(x) = 2\tau'(x)+4\tau(x) \hphantom{\sum\sum} \tau(0)=1, \tau'(0) =2.$$
This is a constant coefficient second order ODE that can be solved with the ansatz $\tau=e^{rx}$ which gives us that $$ r^2 = 2r+4 \Rightarrow r = 1 \pm \sqrt{5}.$$
So the general solution looks like $$ \tau(x) = \alpha \exp\left((1-\sqrt{5})x\right) + \beta \exp\left((1-\sqrt{5})x\right) $$ which gives $$\alpha = \frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{10}, \beta=\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{10}$$ when plugging in the initial conditions. Taking derivatives, we then get that $$ T_m = \frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{10}\left(1+\sqrt{5} \right)^m + \frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{10}\left(1-\sqrt{5} \right)^m$$ And since $m=2n$ the answer to your question is $$ \boxed{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{10}\left(1+\sqrt{5} \right)^{2n} + \frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{10}\left(1-\sqrt{5} \right)^{2n}}$$

Thank you for this very in depth answer. Just a question - maybe I am misinterpreting your answer - but for the case where there is one vertical tile, do you leave the space to the right of this tile empty? or is the recurrence relation somehow taking this into account in a way I don't realise?
Do you think that there could be an application of the compositions of Generating Functions in this case?

That would be https://oeis.org/A102592 .

@R.J.Mathar thanks for this. I am struggling to find the recurrence relation that describes this sequence. Would you have any ideas? How do you know that this is the correct sequence?

The recurrence in A102592 is a(n) = 12a(n-1)-16a(n-2), this is what the OEIS "index entries for linear recurrences with..." means.
The Reinberger formula is basically the 3rd equation in the OEIS.

@R.J.Mathar thanks for this. I am struggling to try to justify why that is the recurrence relation. Would you have any pointers?

So, the recurrence relation works by considering the number of ways, counting the colors, that we can tile the grid. But, because we can have a vertical tile, it's easier to consider the ways we can color a grid with half-tile increments in the horizontal direction instead of just full tile-ones. In that case, the leftmost tile can be either a vertical tile (this corresponds to the $2T_{m-1}$ term in the recurrence relation), or it can be horizontal tile (which corresponds to the $4T_{m-2}$).

So, the 2 in the first term corresponds to the fact that there are 2 ways the leftmost tile can be vertical--one for each color, and then a tiling with leftmost tile vertical corresponds to either a blue or yellow leftmost tile and some tiliing of the remaining $m-1$ half-tiles. Meanwhile there are four ware the leftmost tiles can be a pair of horizontal tiles (yellow and blue for both the top and bottom), but a tiling in that case corresponds to one of the four ways the leftmost tiles can work, plus a tiling of the remaining $m-2$ half-squares in that case.

Since those are all the options, the $T_m = 2T_{m-1} +4T_{m-2}$ follows, where $m$ counts the number of half-tiles. Since there are $2n$ half tiles in your rectangle,, $T_{2m}$ gives the number you want

@CadeReinberger makes sense thank you!
